# Usar uma Dll que implementa o Refit - erro ao injetar dependência

Tags: c#, dll, injeção-de-dependência

Criei uma api que usa o refit para consumir uma outra api, todos os testes deram certo até ai. Criei uma biblioteca de classes que tem os DTOs, Models, e as interfaces que fazem essa comunicação.
Ao inportar a Dll e recriar os controllers a compilação nao apresenta erros, porem ao executar um endpoint recebo o erro:

```
Unable to resolve service for type 'PolgoApi.DataAcess.Interfaces.IloginData' while attempting to activate 'PolgoApi.Controllers.LoginController'.
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetService(IServiceProvider sp, Type type, Type requiredBy, Boolean isDefaultParameterRequired)
   at lambda_method9(Closure , IServiceProvider , Object[] )
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerActivatorProvider.<>c__DisplayClass7_0.<CreateActivator>b__0(ControllerContext controllerContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerFactoryProvider.<>c__DisplayClass6_0.<CreateControllerFactory>g__CreateController|0(ControllerContext controllerContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
```

Meu Progran

```
using PolgoApi.DataAcess.Interfaces;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

Tentei adicionar as interfaces, porem, elas não possuem um service ou um repositorio que a implementa, ela e usada pelo pacote refit para fazer o consumo da api em questao:

interface:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using PolgoApi.DTO;
using PolgoApi.Model;
using Refit;

namespace PolgoApi.DataAcess.Interfaces
{
    public interface IChanceData
    {
        [Post("/{request.anoCampanha}/{requestQuery.identicicacaoCampanha}/{requestQuery.totalPorPagina}/{requestQuery.paginaAtual}")]
        Task<Chance> GetChances([Header("Authorization")] string token, [FromBody] ChancesRequest requestQuery);
    }
}
```

Não sei como fazer a dll funcionar de forma atomica, sem que a aplicação que a importar tenha que conhecer essas interfaces, alguem tem alguma ideia?

Já tentei adicionar as interfaces no program, porem nao sei como faze-lo sendo que a interface nao mapeia para nemuma classe concreta.

Na lib cheguei a adicionar uma classe que implementa as interfaces, mas não consigo acessar os metodos na outra aplicação.

```
using PolgoApi.DataAcess.Interfaces;
using PolgoApi.DTO;
using PolgoApi.Model;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;


namespace PolgoIntegracao
{
   public class IntegracaoPolgo
   {
       private readonly ITransacoesData _transacaoData;
       private readonly IChanceData _chanceData;
       private readonly IloginData _loginData;

       public IntegracaoPolgo(IloginData loginData, IChanceData chanceData, ITransacoesData transacaoData)
       {
           this._loginData = loginData;
           this._transacaoData = transacaoData;
           this._chanceData = chanceData;
       }
       public async Task<LoginResponse> Autenticacao(AutenticationRequest request)
       {
           var _loginData = new LoginResponse();
           return await _loginData.Autentication(request).ConfigureAwait(false);
       }
       public async Task<Login> Cadastro(CadastroRequest request)
       {
           return await _loginData.Cadastro(request).ConfigureAwait(false);
       }
       public async Task<Chance> GetRaspadinhasAsync(string token, ChancesRequest request)
       {
           return await _chanceData.GetChances(token, request).ConfigureAwait(false);
       }
       public void PostTransacao( TransacaoRequest request, string token)
       {
            _transacaoData.PostTransacao(request, token);
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Essa lib tem que ter algum método pra injetar uma implementação `IloginData`. Na documentação deve ter isso. Sem mais detalhes não tem como te ajudar...

Comment: não sei como implementar isso na lib, tentei procurar outros exemplos ma esta complicado achar. A lib possui uma classe base, que inporta as interfaces:

Comment: Adicionei à pergunta a Implementação da classe que deveria injetar as dependencias

Comment: Como eu comentei anteriormente, o que falta é você registrar uma implementação dessa `IloginData`...

Comment: ela e muito similar à que eu coloquei:

Comment: using PolgoApi.DTO;
using PolgoApi.Model;
using Refit;

namespace PolgoApi.DataAcess.Interfaces
{
    public interface IloginData
    {
        [Post("/login/v1/autenticacao")]
        Task<LoginResponse> Autentication([Body]AutenticationRequest request);
        [Post("/login/v1/logins")]
        //para mandar headers fixos
        //[Headers("X-DiretivaSegura: "segura peão")]
        Task<Login> Cadastro([Body] CadastroRequest request);
    }
}

Comment: eu que criei a lib, por isso nao tem documentação